# `undefined symbol error` involving `libusb` after compiling and installing library on Linux

Tags: linux, makefile, linker, symbols, libusb

I am trying to install the MCC DAQ library (https://github.com/mccdaq/uldaq#build-instructions) from github on my Linux machine. I follow the build and installation intructions but some linking error involving `libusb` seems to occur. When I try to run the `AIn` example I get an `undefined symbol` error:

```
./examples/AIn
Found 1 DAQ device(s)
  [0] USB-1608GX: (020D2FF3)

Connecting to device USB-1608GX - please wait ...
/home/dvarx/Downloads/libuldaq-1.2.1/examples/.libs/AIn: symbol lookup error: /home/dvarx/Downloads/libuldaq-1.2.1/src/.libs/libuldaq.so.1: undefined symbol: libusb_has_capability
```

And the symbol in question is not found in the shared library:

```
nm /home/dvarx/Downloads/libuldaq-1.2.1/src/.libs/libuldaq.so.1 | grep libusb_has
                 U libusb_has_capability
```

When running `./configure && make` I do not get any errors related to `libusb`:

```
...
checking for libusb_init in -lusb-1.0... yes
checking libusb-1.0/libusb.h usability... yes
checking libusb-1.0/libusb.h presence... yes
checking for libusb-1.0/libusb.h... yes
...
```

I checked and should have the required packages installed:

```
apt list --installed | grep libusb

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libusb-0.1-4/focal,now 2:0.1.12-32 amd64 [installed]
libusb-1.0-0-dev/focal,now 2:1.0.23-2build1 amd64 [installed]
libusb-1.0-0/focal,now 2:1.0.23-2build1 amd64 [installed]
libusb-1.0-0/focal,now 2:1.0.23-2build1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libusb-1.0-doc/focal,focal,now 2:1.0.23-2build1 all [installed,automatic]
libusbmuxd6/focal,now 2.0.1-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

One thing I noticed is that if I try to list the symbols in my installed libusb library, no symbols are reported:

```
nm /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0
nm: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0: no symbols
```

I'm not quite sure how I can proceed to debug this issue, maybe someone knows a solution to this?

Comment: use `nm -D` to check dynamic symbols. `libusb-1.0.so` *should* have the symbol in question. However `libusb-0.1` (which you also may have) doesn't. If your build scripts refer to just `libusb.so` or `-lusb`, try changing them to `libusb-1.0.so` or `-lusb-1.0`.

Comment: In the `Makefile`, `LIBS = -lusb-1.0 ` is added by `config`. I tried replacing it with `libusb-1.0.so` but it didn't seem to resolve the issue. I even tried building the library with `libusb-0.1` uninstalled, however, the same problem occurred.

Comment: No idea then. Maybe libuldaq-1.2.1 is built with a static libusb? Or maybe it dlopens libusb.so?

Comment: I recently got back to this issue, I noticed that I can run the program as a superuser, (i.e. `sudo ./examples/AIn` works fine but `./examples/AIn` results in the lookup error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue in the meantime. The problem was that there was another version of `libusb` installed on this particular system and  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contained a path pointing to this version of `libusb`. Launching the program with an adjusted `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` solved the issue.